# Blazor resets bind value

Tags: binding, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm having trouble understanding blazor binding. I have created a basic sample to illustrate the problem I'm facing:

Suppose I want to create a component to choose a day and time like this:
[image: Day time component], with a *Value* property of type DateTime.

First, I create a component to hold the time input:

```
@* TimeInput.razor *@
<input type="time" @onchange=Changed value=@Value.ToString("HH:mm") required>

@code {
    [Parameter] public DateTime Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<DateTime> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    public void Changed(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = DateTime.Parse((string)e.Value!);
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
}
```

Then I create a component with a select input and the TimeInput component created in the previous step:

```
@* DateTimeSelector.razor *@

<select @onchange=DateChanged>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        var date = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1).AddDays(i);
        <option value=@date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
                selected=@(Value.Date == date)>
            @date.ToString("dddd")
        </option>
    }
</select>
<TimeInput Value=Value ValueChanged=TimeChanged />

@code
{
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<DateTime> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private void DateChanged(ChangeEventArgs arg)
        => Value = DateTime.Parse((string)arg.Value!).Add(Value.TimeOfDay);

    private void TimeChanged(DateTime time)
        => Value = Value.Date.Add(time.TimeOfDay);

    private DateTime value;

    [Parameter]
    public DateTime Value
    {
        get => value;
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Value is {value}"); // FOR DEBUGGING
            if (this.value != value)
            {
                this.value = value;
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I test it in a page:

```
@page "/"

<p><DateTimeSelector @bind-Value=@dateTime /></p>
<p>Debug: <input type="text" value=@dateTime /></p>

@code {
    private DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2022, 1, 3, 17, 0, 0);
}
```

When the page is loaded, the component shows with value 2022-01-03 17:00 as expected:
[image]

But as soon as the user change a value (for example, from 5 pm to 6 pm), then the value resets to 0001-01-01 00:00:
[image]

If i take a look at the console I see this:
[image]

So why is this happening? Who's calling (twice) the setter for property *Value* with a default date? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just a small omission. In your `DateTimeSelector`, you have to invoke with the value.

`ValueChanged.InvokeAsync();` => `ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);`

Answer (score 1):

I Have a Similar Issue And didn't Find the appropiate solution, so i was looking for other options and discover Blazorise, it's a component library which has modules like DateEdit or TimeEdit and solve the problem that you have, it's an alternative, could be not what you expect but it's pretty simple to use!

```
<Field>
   <FieldLabel>Date</FieldLabel>
   <DateEdit TValue="DateTime?" Placeholder="Select Date" @bind-Date="@input.date"></DateEdit>
</Field>
```